# How do I add a wordpress blog to a Yii2 Website as a route

Tags: php, wordpress, yii2

I have been working with with Yii2 for a while same as wordpress. I am currently building a website using Yii2. I want to add a wordpress blog to this website. I want to make it in such a way that; when you access www.mydomain.com/blog, it opens the wordpress section of my website and shows post made in wordpress etc.

I have done some research online and I have not gotten a clear procedure on how to achieve this task.

In a nutshell, I want a route of Yii2 to be directed to run a fully functional wordpress blog.

Any Advise on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't put WordPress installation under `blog` directory?

Comment: No, I am open to any procedure that will work.

Comment: I am using Yii2 and everythin here is routed

Comment: Yii will handle only URLs to  resource that does not exists. If you create `blog` directory with WP in it, it should work as regular WordPress installation without involving Yii.

Comment: Yes, but I wont be able to have the same Navigation bar running through the application. I just need my blog route of my nav bar to display a Blog section.

Comment: so, I have home, about, services, blog etc. home, about, services are all build in Yii2 but blog is build in Wordpress. But I want the blog section to coexist with other sections. If I install as proposed, I do not know how I am going to get the websites synchronize

Comment: @NgesBrian Then... just make a Dir `blog` in your root for `wordpress` and specify `apache` or `nginx` directives for wordpress in configs.

Answer (score 0):

Just create `blog` directory and put your `wordpress` files in it. but cause of wordpress has very very plugins and some of plugins has bugs, I suggest you to change your `core Yii2` directory to upper route. for example:

Index of your www path:

```
../
/assets // your Yii2 assets directory
/blog // wordpress directory
index.php
backend.php
.htaccess
```

put Yii2 core files to another directory in upper of `www`:
core directories are : `backend`,`frontend`,`console`,`vendore` and etc.

then edit path in index.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../core/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../core/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../core/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../core/frontend/config/bootstrap.php';
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../core/common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../core/common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../core/frontend/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../core/frontend/config/main-local.php'
);
```

and do it same for your `backend.php`

then add this line to your `.htaccess` after `RewriteEngine On` :

```
RewriteRule ^backend(.*) backend.php
```

**Note:** If you have error in assets, change your `public $baseUrl` in `AppAsset.php` and other AssetBundles to `@web/assets/`

Comment: I am using Yii Basic templete

Comment: So just edit `$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/web.php');` to `$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../core/config/web.php');` after putting base core files in upper directory

Comment: so in the nutshell, my root directory should have a core folder that contains all my yii2 files eg models, controllers, vendors, assets, configs etc and my blog is my wordpress. I dont get the logic behind it

Comment: Yes but no assets directory, this is because of prevent to access your base and core files,log files and other important directly, because of some wordpress plugins has a dangerous bugs and I think with this jobs it can be safer :)

Comment: oki, after setting it up in this format, how do I host in shared hosting to make sure that, only mydomain.com is pointing to my web folder while mydomain,com/blog reads the wordpress blog??

Comment: yes. `/blog` is your wordpress, `/assets` is your assets directory and `index.php` is your Yii2 basic project, all core files is in `upper` folder. mydomain.com is your site and mydomain.com/blog is your wordpress blog

Comment: remember that index.php is inside the web folder and I dont want to have web folder on my url

Comment: Now, my question is that, when I shall host and point my entire application that is mydomain.com to myprojectfolder/web, I won't be able to access my blog since it is located at myprojectfolder/blog which is out of myprojectfolder/web

Comment: where does myprojectfolder/web come from ?

Comment: oki, if I am getting it right, I have the asset, web, blog and core folders in my root directory. my web is reading everything from the core folder and everything is fine. Now, when I want to host, online to be able to have everything working as it works now without the web clause in my url, how do I do it ??

Comment: ok, I think i found where is our discosion problem :). your problem is why address is domain.com/web/index.php. just move `index.php` and `assets` directory to `www` route. and all of other files goes upper folder. think your route folder has 2 directory `assets`,`blog` and 2 file `index.php`,`.htaccess`.

Comment: if I do it that way, what will be the content of the index.php. remember that by default, the index.php of yii2 is in the web folder.

Comment: Just change the `config/web.php` path to where really is in.

Comment: anyways, when I shall reach on that bridge, I will cross. thanks so much for the help